# I will think as if I had already taken it???(as a rejection)

Tags: expressions

The situation is that somebody tries to give me something as a reward(a kind of gift?). But I don't need it, but also I don't want to say to him/her, " no thanks!" I think it's kind of rude because he/she tries to show me his sincerity. So hmmm, in this case, I want to express like this, even though I didn't actually take it, I want to say as if I had already taken it. Are there any proper expressions for this situation? 
How about this.. I'll think it I had already taken it. Haha this is literally translated. Tell me how to say in this situation. Always thanks. :}

Comment: Do you mean appreciation rather than sincerity?

Answer (score 1):

An informal, idiomatic way to say this generally (at least in parts of the US, and maybe elsewhere) would be

> "Thanks so much, [**I'm all set**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/i-m-all-set)." (MacMillan Dictionary)

or, even more briefly,

> "Thanks, [**I'm good**](http://www.idiomeanings.com/im-good/)." (idioMeanings)

The "but" is implied--it sounds politer to avoid it if you can, since it basically negates what comes before. "I'm all set" and "I'm good" in this context mean roughly "I'm content as I am; I don't need anything additional at this moment."

Whether one of these phrases is acceptable or even recognized might depend on region (see [Is the use of "all set" exclusive to certain regions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21507/is-the-use-of-all-set-exclusive-to-certain-regions) and [Difference between "I'm fine" and "I'm good"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41818/difference-between-im-fine-and-im-good)). I'm from the Midwestern US and use both.

You can also reverse these, adding back in the "but" and saying more about your appreciation, to really emphasize the thanks:

> I'm good, but thanks for thinking of me!
>
> I'm all set, but thank you so much for the offer, I really appreciate it!

and so forth.

Finally, you can actually use either phrase without any thanks at all (just plain *"I'm good"* or *"I'm all set"*) when someone offers you something, and they still convey a very slight, very casual sense of gratitude (see the links in block quotes above). This would be the least formal and least thankful-sounding option, though. Used most often in situations such as a sales clerk asking if you need help finding something, or your significant other offering to get you a drink when he/she gets his/her own.

(I note that Urban Dictionary also suggests "[I'm straight](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=i%27m%20straight)" and "[I'm square](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I%27m%20square)" as synonyms, FWIW. I recognize both, but wouldn't think to use either.)

Answer (score 0):

You want to show appreciation for a gift while at the same time declining it because it's not useful to you?

I'd go with something like "*That's very kind of you, but ... [reason]*"

If you want a little more emphasis you can explain that not only are they kind, but you're also grateful: "*That's very kind of you, I do appreciate the offer, but ... [reason]*"

That's a rather formal/polite way of saying it in British English. In an less formal context or with a close acquaintance (or as a default option in less politeness-heavy cultures such as Australia or America), one could simply say "*No thanks mate, I've got one already*".

Answer (score 0):

It would be impossible to use as is in your case of a bonafide  act of kindness, but [“Let’s not and say we did”](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/let's_not_and_say_we_did) is a **similar** notion used to “[indicate] that the speaker does not agree with a proposed action, and does not wish to participate” (from *Wiktionary*).
 (similar in the sense that one party believes  that it might/would be better to **pretend** that the action has occurred when it really hasn’t)

Maybe you could put a positive spin on it and say:
“That’s so kind of you, but I already have one of those. Let’s just give it to someone else and say/pretend that you gave me the one I already have, ok?”

Answer (score 0):

Thank them for ***their*** offer.

In French, after a doing someone a favour, we use the phrase, "Merci, tant que," following the offer for reward which loosely translated as, "Thanks, all the same," in English. You might want to strengthen the response with, "You're very kind to offer."

Although it amounts to a refusal of an offer, there's no negative used and no explanation is necessary. It's as though the effort you volunteered is already worth the simple expression of thanks offered without further remedy or reward.